# package.json vs package-lock.json vs semantic versioning

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

Here is my understanding:

- The `package.json` defines which dependencies and which versions are used. Depending on whether there is a `^` or a `~` before the version number, the exact versions can vary based on the versions available in the npm registry at the time of `npm install`.
- If there is a `package-lock.json` this file defines the exact versions that will be installed, when running `npm install`.

If this is correct, then here are the questions:

- When specifying precise versions in the `package.json` (i.e. without `^` or `~`) is it correct, that there is basically no need for a `package-lock.json`, because the versions  are already "locked" due to the precise version in the `package.json`?
- I would say it is important to be sure to have the versions "locked" in order to have the same behavior on all environments, be it the local dev environments as well as the build server(s). So I would suggest using the above approach: Precise versions in the `package.json` with no `package-lock.json`. The same result could however also be achieved by using "unprecise versions" (`^` or `~`) and locking the versions with `package-lock.json`. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: `package-lock.json` lists all dependencies of your dependencies

Comment: "no" and "not really", respectively. Remember that your dependencies have dependencies too, and remember what semver means: any patch version difference _does not change the API at all_, and any minor version difference _does not change anything in a backward compatibility breaking way_. So for reputable packages that properly follow semver, you absolutely want `^` so that you're always on the latest minor and patch versions. However, not every package follows semver, and some straight up lie and say they do when they clearly don't, so that's where your diligence comes in.

Comment: But aren't the dependencies of the dependencies fixed for a specific/published version in the npm registry? Or in other words: If one of my dependencies updates its dependencies, this will lead to a new version being published, right? Or can a random npm package change its dependencies without publishing a new version?